# Google Classroom API - Student's "emailAddress" and "photoUrl" are not coming in the response

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-classroom

I have a query regarding Student's Response of courses.

I am not getting two parameters in API call (emailAddress and photoUrl)

While calling the URL to the  API "https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/{courseId}/students" via my code.

I am getting the following response:

```
{
  "students": [
    {
      "courseId": "303431573",
      "userId": "104377167089915657872",
      "profile": {
        "id": "104377167089915657872",
        "name": {
          "givenName": "student2",
          "familyName": "User",
          "fullName": "student2 User"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "courseId": "303431573",
      "userId": "104304056850029354748",
      "profile": {
        "id": "104304056850029354748",
        "name": {
          "givenName": "student1",
          "familyName": "User",
          "fullName": "student1 User"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But, when I execute it in Google Classroom's developer console by passing same courseId, I am getting response as follows:

```
{
 "students": [
  {
   "courseId": "303431573",
   "userId": "104377167089915657872",
   "profile": {
    "id": "104377167089915657872",
    "name": {
     "givenName": "student2",
     "familyName": "User",
     "fullName": "student2 User"
    },
    "emailAddress": "student2_rvnqrmpxeraft-mcygui@classroom-dev.com",
    "photoUrl": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg"
   }
  },
  {
   "courseId": "303431573",
   "userId": "104304056850029354748",
   "profile": {
    "id": "104304056850029354748",
    "name": {
     "givenName": "student1",
     "familyName": "User",
     "fullName": "student1 User"
    },
    *"emailAddress": "student1_kb5ysml_yw4l2ecbu581@classroom-dev.com",
    "photoUrl": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg"*
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Praveen - to access emailAddress and photoURL you'll need to request the following additional OAuth scopes:

- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.photos`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.emails`

Check out https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/auth for more details.